# Crystal Reports runtime for Visual Studio 2010 not working in Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Our web application used the old Crystal Reports XI Rel 2 activeX to render the reports called from classic ASP. We would like now to have it run alongside the new Crystal Reports 13 run time to render reports called from ASP.NET.

We installed the exe found in http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 (support pack 3). On our dev machines (windows XP) everything went alright, and we were able to design and render reports in both technologies. We tried to deploy it today to a client's server (Windows Server 2008 64 bit) and it obviously didn't work.

If we first try to open the new report then the old one, <s>they both fail, but with completely generic and therefore useless error messages ones like "Error while creating report".</s> the new one is OK, but the old one fails with message "Invalid TLV record".

Inversely, if, after restarting iis, we first try to open an old report (CR XI R2 from classic ASP), it shows correctly, but the new one (CR 13) gives this error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {F734A321-8381-4FFD-A614-139E8906DC83} failed due to the following
>   error: 80000003 One or more arguments are invalid (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80000003).

We tried to google this error; the only meaningful result was [this thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2135647) but it didn't help us.

Thank you

**EDIT**: ok, the first error was simply that the .rpt files were being left out of the deployed folder. So it really boils down to an incompatibility of the CR runtimes, maybe?

**EDIT 2**: Yes, it is definitely it. We moved the new report in another virtual directory running under another application pool and now they both work, regardless of what is instantiated first. So is there any way we can gradually migrate our existing records, ie have a period where both run times coexist and are used by the same virtual directory?

Comment: When you deployed the site, where did you deploy it to? Was it C:\wwwroot\inetpub

Comment: We have our own setup that deploys it in a folder under Program Files

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. As I had just installed CR 13 without a reboot, I thought I'd try a reboot of the server. After the reboot, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error - reboot didn´t help.
Installed SAP Crystal Reports runtime 13.0.0.99 on Win7 but got several errors registering components during installation - think that is the cause of the problem.

Downloaded and installed CR Runtime 13.0.21.2533 (32bit)
from
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_21.msi
That installed without errors but didn´t work either :-(

Comment: Version "CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_20.msi" finally did the trick for me

Comment: http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_20.msi